# Finding Harmonic Conjugate of the form $\phi(xy)$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I want to find a harmonic function of form $\phi(xy)$ where $\phi$ is an unknown function. To be harmonic, it must satisfy the laplacian equation. So by chain rule i compute the second partial derivatives and now have a second order partial equation. Namely, $\phi''(xy)(y^2 + x^2) = 0$. However, doesn't this mean that $\phi''(xy) = 0$ or $y^2 + x^2 = 0$?

Solving the LHS is
$$\int \phi''(xy) = \phi'(xy)$$
$$\int \phi'(xy) = \phi(xy) = 0$$

But this doesn't actually tell me what $\phi$ is. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you did your chain rule correctly? Even if so, your integrations aren't going to be correct, because you don't have such a "nice" FTC in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fine down to $\phi''(xy)=0$. The you can put $z=xy$, so
$$ \phi''(z) = 0. $$
You can then integrate up in the usual way:
$$ \phi'(z) = A \\
\phi(z) = Az+B = Axy+B. $$
(Check: this makes sense, since it is the imaginary part of the complex function $Az^2+iB$, 
$$\frac{1}{2}A(x+iy)^2+iB = \frac{1}{2}A(x^2-y^2)+ i(Axy+B).) $$